# Solving Trigonometric Limits: Can Someone Explain Why There are t(s) in the Numerator and Denominator?

Tags: calculus, limits

I understand that the commutative property of multiplication allows me to shift the trig identities, however, I do not understand where the t's come from. Also, why is there no t in the middle term?   [image]

Why are there t's in the denominator and numerator. What law of real numbers allows this?

Comment: This is a common technique called an artifice: you can add some term to an expression and then subtract it, without changing the value. Similarly, you can multiply and then divide by the same factor. The benefit is obtained by regrouping.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs for two reasons. First it is assuming that the limit of $\cfrac {\sin t}t$ is known.

Then it is using the fact that $\cfrac tt=1$ to put a $t$ in the numerator and a matching $t$ in the denominator: equivalent to multiplying by $\cfrac tt$, so that the known limits can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Because they want to use
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin 6t}{6t}=1,\ \ \ \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2t}{\sin 2t}=1.$$
But $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{\cos 6t}=\frac{1}{1}=1,$$
so no need for $t$ in the middle term.

Comment: So this an arbitrary rule by mathematicians to make something work?

Comment: @user137452: Well, this is one of the manipulations in such a question, I think.